# how to load drupal views content into a div on the same page

Tags: drupal-6

I have on my site a page which contain a div in the center and on the right side i have a view which display 4 boxes all are created under the same content type formed from a title ,subtitle an abstract and the body but i dont want to show the body in the right boxes.I need when i click on any of the title ,abstract of these boxes to display the body of the corresponding clicked box in the div at the same page ,each time we click a box its content will replace the old div content.
how can i do it in drupal i cant find a real solution i 've looked over but no solution.
any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comments for some reason, so take this as a comment (which shouldn't have a rep. requirement in the first place by the way), unless it answers your question.

I think you're trying to hide the body of your view output unless someone clicks the title? If that's the case, find out what the body text has as a CSS class with Firebug, and apply a "display: none;" to that class. Next you'll be adding a jQuery click handler to the title element that changes "display: none;" to "display: block;"

Again, this should be a comment asking for clarification but since I'm unable to do that, I answered the question I thought you were asking.

Comment: no i need to show the content of the clicked node in the div on the same page.to clarify more for example i have in the box a title called "News" when i click on the News title i need to show the body of the current node in div placed on the page.